# Can MQTT be used to set data for an IoT device?

Tags: mqtt, iot

I know MQTT uses publish/subscribe, meaning all clients can pub/sub to any topic and all clients have to be connected to an MQTT broker.

Is it also good practice to use MQTT to *set* data for an IoT device?

Let's imagine the IoT device is a smart light which can be controlled via a web app. The web app will subscribe for the r/g/b values and the intensity and then visualize the values in the app.

But is it also good practice to set data via MQTT? Meaning the web app will then publish to the topic `/deviceID/set/r/255` (or something like this) and only the IoT device subscribes to the topic `/deviceID/set/#`.

If this is not common practice what are the options?
Do we have to implement multiple protocols for one IoT device?

Comment: It's probably worth taking a look at [sparkplug](https://sparkplug.eclipse.org/specification/) ("a specification that defines how best to use MQTT in real-time, mission-critical industrial infrastructures").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly valid to send configuration values to devices via MQTT as you describe. Just make sure that there's strong validation for these values to avoid any abuse or security issues.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is perfectly acceptable, and fairly common. Just like you suggest, each device has unique ID that the web app knows about and subscribes to so that it is the only devices that normally sees the requests directed towards it. I typically use the device serial number for the ID when available.

I usually create a single top-level topic field, like "commands/..." for out-bound commands to the devices, i.e. "commands/deviceID/..." so that you can setup a listener to watch the command traffic to all the devices, "commands/#", isolated from all the other data flying around.

I use the topic to specify the common request and then the payload for the variable parameters. So `commands/deviceID/set`, for the topic and then (perhaps JSON) payload of `{ value: 25 }`. I think of the topic as the function name and the payload as the function arguments.

If you can use MQTT v5, there is a somewhat standardized way of doing remote procedure calls (RPC) over MQTT. v5 has standardized message metadata, called "properties", so that the device can send back a reply to each specific command. The requestor (web app in your case) specifies a topic on which the reply should be sent back (Response Topic) and a unique correlation ID (Correlation Data). Thus the device can receive a command, process it, and tell the web app when it's done and whether it succeeded or failed, etc.

This may be more than you need, but it just shows that the command request/reply pattern is common enough that there is now support in the standard itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using MQTT to both publish and subscribe for an IoT device is a common practice and can provide a unified communication mechanism. In your scenario, where the IoT device is a smart light controlled by a web app, it's absolutely reasonable to use MQTT for both setting data (publishing) and receiving updates (subscribing)

But just in case you want to explore other options for communication between the web app and the IoT device, you can go with:

1. HTTP RESTful API
2. WebSockets - Yes it can do bidirectional communication if configured properly.
   3.CoAP - Constrained Application Protocol is another lightweight protocol used for IoT Devices.

To answer your last question do we have to implement multiple protocols in an IoT device? Yes and No, it depends upon the scenario and which protocol is compatible with your gateway (most imp) and your environmment.

Answer (score 0):

There are two views on that:

A logical view:
There different MQTT solution in use.
Some reduce MQTT to a peer-to-peer communication, and do not support the "message-broker" function.
And some use a "message broker" and setup unique "group topic" for each peer. Which one works and scales, is up to your implementation.

A IP view:
The most use MQTT mainly for the feature "pushing data" to the device. That works, if the ip-route is available. And many other protocols will also able to send data to the device, if the ip-route is available. Especially UDP based protocols benefit from such route, if the upper protocol is designed to be used bidirectional (e.g. CoAP with "role exchange). The nasty point is, that common network equipment may close that ip-route sooner for UDP than TCP. Anyway, in the end, if you want such an ip-route you will need frequently pings or reconnects.
The idea, to keep that data on the server until the device notifies the server (and creates with that a fresh ip-route) works pretty well with the very most protocols I know.